# CSS half circle background

Tags: css

What I am trying to achieve:
[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zb58v.png)

What my code currently looks like:

```css
.half-circle {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: black;">
  <div class="half-circle">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/WBtkahj.png" />
  </div>
</div>
<div>Some text here that should't be moved</div>
```

I've tried using padding with a white background and 500 radius, but it pushes the text down.

Comment: The code you've included isn't really complete enough to what you're going for. I want to help, but I don't want to do a bunch of busy work before getting to the actual solution.

Comment: What radius/padding? All you've provided is a white background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with CSS if you give your `.half-circle` a `border-bottom-left-radius` and `border-bottom-right-radius`. That will round the bottom corners of the shape into a half circle. I also added some extra style to match your screenshot a little better.

```css
.container {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.half-circle {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 800px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 800px;
  padding: 10px 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
   
img {
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="background-color: #000;">
  <div class="half-circle">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/WBtkahj.png" />
  </div>
</div>
<div>Some text here that should't be moved</div>
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Thank you very much! I have been trying since I posted about an hour ago...

Comment: You're welcome!! If you've found this answer useful, please accept it as the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [`radial-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient) and tune a bit the sizing

```css
.half-circle {
  min-height: 12vw;
  padding-bottom: 4%;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at top, white 17vw, transparent 17.1vw)
}

.half-circle img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 15vw
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: black;">
  <div class="half-circle">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/WBtkahj.png" />
  </div>
</div>
<div>Some text here that should'nt be moved</div>
```

Comment: you can also remove the outre wrapper and include the black color in the gradient